# jQuery-HTML div selection -select only one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am raw to jquery, and this is my first question.Pardon if it is trivial.
I have the following html page structure existing-

```
<div class="button-footer" data-role="footer"....>
  <div class="class1" data-role="navbar">
     <ul>
          <li>//these are buttons button 1
           <li>//button 2
     </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now i need to do the following-
I need to have a different ul based on some condition i.e if condition is true replace the entire static ul with another.How to I proceed? Where should the replacement static ul list be paced in -the same html or js file?I am confused please take a look. Any help is very much appreciated.
This is what i have tried so far-

```
<div class="button-footer" data-role="footer"....>
  <div class="class1" data-role="navbar">
     <ul>
          <li>// button 1
           <li>//button 2
     </ul>
  </div>
<div class="class2" data-role="navbar">
     <ul>
          <li>// button 3
           <li>//button 4
     </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

then in .js page, i did this-

```
 if(condition)
    $( ".class1" ).remove();

else
   $( ".class2" ).remove();
```

the point according to me is that since both the ul's are static,why not place them in the html itself and do a remove?does this makes sense?

Comment: Have you made any attempts yet and are willing to provide us with some relevant code snippets?

Comment: create a fiddle with the problem.

Comment: you can create two uls with hide and show class. in js change add or remove class based on the condition. or a second solution is change the html content of li based on the condition. Please provide some jsfiddle or your effort in code to help.

Answer (score 2):

Use `replaceWith` in `jquery`

The .replaceWith() method removes content from the DOM and inserts new content in its place with a single call.

```
var cond = "3";
if (cond == "2") {

    $(".customul").replaceWith("<ul><li>hello </li> </ul>");

} else if (cond == "3") {

    $(".customul").replaceWith("<ul><li>hello user </li> </ul>");
} else

{
    $(".customul").replaceWith("<ul><li>hi </li> </ul>");

}

<div class="button-footer" data-role="footer">
    <div class="class1" data-role="navbar">this is data-role div
        <div class="customul">
            <ul>
                <li>hi</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4ZS8g/1/

Comment: This might not be what is intended since $( ".class1" ).replaceWith('..') will replace <div class="class1" data-role="navbar"> with the new <ul>

Comment: @vasa tO SOLVE THIS problem ,we can take ul in another div.check updated answer

Comment: That's not there in the qn. Also, the new <div> serves no purpose here other than being replaced later on.

Comment: @vasa .There are so many ways dude. you can write this class class="customul" in ul tag .if you don't want to add new div.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the HTML based on some condition, place it in the JS.

```
if(condition) {
  var new_ul_html = '<ul>.... </ul>'
  $('.button-footer .class1').html(new_ul_html);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var x;
    alert("");
    for (x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        if (x % 2 === 0) {
           $(".class1").append("<ul><li>Even</li><li>"+x+"</li></ul>");
        } else {
            $(".class1").append("<ul><li>Odd</li><li>"+x+"</li></ul>");
        }
    }


});
```

Try in that way, may be this will be the solution for your requirement.

check code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/hqaUE/2/

Comment: If You want to remove the existing ul you can give $(".class1").empty(); at the starting. So before appending it will remove ul from your div.